# Quickly open table in SQLDeveloper

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use Oracle SQL Developer for a pretty big project, with a great number of tables.

Is there a way I can quickly open a table by typing its name ?

For example, in IntelliJIDEA, the `ctrl + shift + N` shortcut opens a small pop-in window with a field, where I can type the file's name. Files containing the search text in their names are displayed, and I can quickly open one of them by tapping `Enter`.

I know tables are sorted alphabeticaly in the left-hand side pannel, but I have many tables, I believe this would save me some time.

Is there something similar in Oracle SQLDeveloper ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the View menu there is a 'Find DB Objects' option, which opens a (dockable, and docked by default I think) window; with your connection selected you can find any object by name. Not quite as fast as you want maybe, but you can leave that window open if you have room I suppose. You can use wildcards if necessary.

If you're in an SQL Worksheet you can right-click on a table name and choose 'Popup Describe', which opens the same object view in a new window, but that doesn't help if you don't know the whole name.

Just starting to type a table name (after a `from`!) in an SQL Worksheet will bring up an auto-complete list of matches, if you have that configured (Preferences->Code Editor->Completion Insight).

Comment: Thanks ! The first solution is pretty close to what I'm looking for. I didn't know the second, which is nice too. I knew the last one though ;)

Answer (score 4):

Very old question but I had the same problem and the answer provided does not open table.

In the SQL Worksheet you can right click a table's name (You have to write it first!) and click "Open Declaration".

The short-cut is not assigned, you can manually assign it via Others -> Open Declaration.

Comment: It works in connexion shell panel, but not from a open sql file. Ctrl+click opens the table definition in my version. (edit: with a file, a connection must be selected first :)

Answer (score -3):

use Ctrl+spacebar for showing dropdown of table names.

Comment: Could you add a reference to the documentation please?